# How I can print a collapsible Jquery mobile,I'm having alist instead of collapsible result,using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sending a request using Ajax to a php page,and it prints the results just fine but not in the form I want it,it list them but not in collapsible form tha's the php code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<?php 


  
  
  $array= json_decode(str_replace('\\','', $_GET["markets"]));
  $category=array("Food","Electronics");
 
  echo '<div data-role="collapsible"><h1>'.$array[0].'</h1><b>Im</b></div>';
  
 
  
   
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a new collapsible item for each entry if you want multiple headers...

```
<?php 
// display the results returned
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" data-       collapsed="true">
<h3><?= $line["SPAM"] ?></h3>
<p><?= $line["TRY"] ?><p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah I was willing to do that,but I was testing on one entry if it can print

Comment: the array is already passed to the script the problem is with the form not the data it gives me the same result it just alist